# How Cocoa App interact with Command line tool?

Tags: cocoa, command-line

Yes, I know about NSTask.

For my example, I want to use command `python` in my GUI Cocoa app.

How do you run a sub command in Cocoa app? And how can you have a Cocoa app  communicate with the command line tool?

Thank you for any answer.
Sorry for my pool english.

Comment: Why doesn't NSTask work for you?

Comment: @shebang. I run python with NSTask, and then cocoa app has no responding in python subcommand. No output of pipe. Other more how cocoa app  communate with subcommand of python?

Comment: NSTask has standardInput and standardOutput properties that you can use to communicate with python's sys.stdin and sys.stdout.